# R metR::ReadNetCDF for input file with "years" as time unit

Tags: r, data.table, netcdf4, metr

While it is not consistent with the Unidata conventions and recommendations, some netcdf files have a time variable with units of the form "years since {some_date}". An
[Example file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-F700xDCJRTVFO1Vebzn1WfkRJVZ-Av3/view?usp=sharing) was obtained from the [KNMI Climate Explorer](https://climexp.knmi.nl/). With the `R` package `metR` version `0.11.0` reading in such a file using `ReadNetCDF()` yields a reasonable output (as in, a date/time unambiguously in the correct year), at least for multi-decadal length data with reference date near the middle of the year. With `metR 0.14.0`, `nc_ts = ReadNetCDF("sample_yrtime.nc")` yields the warning:

```
In .parse_time(ncfile$dim[[dims[i]]]$vals, ncfile$dim[[dims[i]]]$units,:
time unit has unrecognised units: years. Not parsing.
```

The `time` column in the output `data.table` is essentially an integer index. Is there a way to extract the reference date ({some_date}) or to recover the correct year for each data point using `metR >= 0.14`? At the moment I'm manually reading the reference date with other software and then doing something like:

```
library(data.table)
yr0 = 1960
nc_ts[, yr := time + yr0]
```

Comment: You seem to be describe a bug in the package, given it was working in an earlier version. You’d be better raising an issue on GitHub https://github.com/eliocamp/metR

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I get the sense from the source code that it was a deliberate change along the lines of a similar recent change in python `xarray`, but I will check!